# Does ending an encounter phase on a street trigger sky monster movement?

Tags: arkham-horror, sky-monster, arkham-horror-2ndedition, monster-movement

If I have an encounter with an investigator that results in moving said investigator to a street and there are monsters waiting in the sky, do they move to that street and encounter that investigator?

I would say they don't move straight away but since after the encounter phase you resolve the mythos phase they would move to the investigator then.

Is that so?

Answer (score 0):

The rules for flying monsters are as following:

> When a flying monster moves during the Mythos Phase, it obeys the
> following rules

and

> B) If the flying monster is in a location or street area with no
> investigators and there are one or more investigators in a connected
> street area, it moves into that street area. If there is more than one
> connected street area containing investigators, it moves towards the
> investigator in those street areas with the lowest current Sneak skill
> (including any relevant equipment and skills; if there is a tie, the
> first player chooses which investigator the monster moves towards)

The sky is just another location

> The Sky is a holding area considered to be a street area that is
> connected to every street area in Arkham. Flying monsters in the Sky
> can swoop down on investigators anywhere in the streets of Arkham.
> Note that monsters in the Sky count against the monster limit

Therefore your reading of the rules is right, it would not move right away, only when the next mythos phase starts.